# Exclude file from compilation during karma test runs

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I am using angular-cli with Karma, and I need to exclude a particular file from being compiled when running unit tests.

The file in question is referenced in the error below, where it cannot be compiled due to a module not being present it relies on.

[image]

This file is used by other projects where the module will be present and so compiles fine, its just in this particular project it does not need compilation but still needs to be exported.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
index.ts
    - /src
    - /testing
```

In my index.ts file I have a single export:

```
export * from './src/core';
```

TS source files under my `testing` folder are getting picked up by the compiler, and I am unsure why as I am not importing any files under this folder in files under my `src` folder or anywhere else from what I can tell.

I want to prevent the compiler from picking up my testing folder altogether, but I cannot get it to ignore it.

I am using angular-cli, and in my .angular-cli.json file I have these lines:

```
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
```

Both of these files are located under my `src` folder, I tried adding some exclude patterns to my tsconfig.spec.json like so:

```
"exclude": [
        "../testing",
        "testing"
    ]
```

But this made no difference.

I then wondered if karma was definitely using my tsconfig.spec.json file and so I added the following:

```
 karmaTypescriptConfig : {
        tsconfig: '.src/tsconfig.spec.json',
    }
```

But again, still no difference is made, my testing folder gets picked up by the compiler when preparing to run my tests.

I am unsure what else to try, I have updated my versions of TypeScript(3.1.6) and Karma(3.1.1) to the latest.

Has anyone got any ideas on what may be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Shoudn't `'.src/tsconfig.spec.json'` be `'./src/tsconfig.spec.json'`?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your path is not enough precise. Could we have your project pseudo tree view ? And especially the path of the file you want to exclude ?

The config file may expect something like this :

```
"exclude": [
        "someFolder/**/o3-test-harness.class.ts"
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, see my updated question with much more detail which may help

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the exclude file route into angular.json file in test configuration.

Example:

```
test: {...
 "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/your_rute_file/name_file.ts"],
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the file that need to remove in the tsconfig.spec.json file

```
    {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "yourdirectory to file/**/file that does not need to compile in testing"
 ]
}
```

so it will look like that,after run the unit tests this will exclude the file in the exclude section.

Comment: I have already tried this, I did mention this in my original question too

Answer (score 0):

In the file,

> tsconfig.spec.json

You can add the exclude array as follows,

```
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"dist",
"**/tests/*.test.ts",
"src/tests"
```

]

so your final output will be as follow

[image]

Comment: yeah, you have done this but excluding file path not properly given.

Comment: How is what you have suggested different to what I an doing?

Answer (score -1):

Karma runs its tests on `dist directory`. So, If you exclude your `tesing directory`, it won't go into your compiled `dist directory`.

In the file

> tsconfig.json

Just add following code

```
"exclude": [
    "./testing"
]
```

Writing this code should solve your problem. 
Let me know if this works.